# Trying to set flex richtexteditor's default font-size

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I just want to lock or set a default font size for the rich text editor. I tried setting font-size = 16, which although it did set the default to 16, also made all the labels etc... in the editor to font size 16.

Answer (score 2):

You want to set the font size on the textArea of your RichTextEditor, which is a sub component of your editor.  In ActionScript you could do this in a creation complete event handler like so:

```
myRichTextEditor.textArea.setStyle("fontSize", 16);
```

Hope that helps.